# Does length $[0,1]$ = length $(0,1)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So we know that the length of an interval $[a,b]$ is simply $b-a$ but does this hold if the interval is open? Or if one of the sides are open, like $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$?

Also, can I just confirm that the outer lebesgue measure of an interval is it's length, right?

Comment: Yes to all of them (for Lebesgue measure)

Comment: By any reasonable definition of length, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a<b$, by definition we have
$$\text{length}([a,b]):=\int_a^b~\mathrm{d}x=\left[x\right]^b_a=\text{length}((a,b))=\text{length}((a,b])=\text{length}([a,b)).$$